# Is there a replacement for aspnetboilerplate IIocResolver.ResolveAll?

Tags: abp

Is there a comparible interface / functionality in abp.io ?

I need something like this:

```
public PaymentGatewayStore(IIocResolver iocResolver)
{
    _iocResolver = iocResolver;
}

public List<PaymentGatewayModel> GetActiveGateways()
{
    var gateways = _iocResolver.ResolveAll<IPaymentGatewayConfiguration>();

    return gateways.Where(gateway => gateway.IsActive).Select(gateway => new PaymentGatewayModel
    {
        GatewayType = gateway.GatewayType,
        SupportsRecurringPayments = gateway.SupportsRecurringPayments
    }).ToList();
}
```

Geert Veenstra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `IEnumerable<IYourService>` to inject all implementations of an interface. Alternatively, you can use `IServiceProvider.GetServices<IYourService>()`.
This is standard Dependency Injection system of the AspNet Core. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#service-registration-methods).